# How to resize the menu bar of the given image for mobile and tablet devices in HTML and CSS coding?

Tags: html, css

[image]

How can i `resize` the `menubar` of the `image` for `mobile` and `tablet` devices in `HTML` and `CSS` coding?

Comment: put your some code too, so we can easily answer to your problem

Answer (score 1):

for mobile devices put your CSS in this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { }
```

and for tablet use

```
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) { }
```

Comment: Yes, use this media query for your devices